# Mapping boolean at post request doesn't work - thymeleaf spring

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm currently building a webservice with spring jpa and thymeleaf.

My Model 'Question.class' has a OneToMany relationship to my Model 'Answer.class' :

```java
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Answer.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "questionAnswerId") 
private List<Answer> answers;
```

as well has my 'Answer.class' a ManyToOne relationship to 'Question.class' :

```java
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Question.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="question_answer_id") 
private Question questionAnswerId;
```

My Controller Method to update the Entity Question:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/frageDetail/updateQuestion/{id}")
public String updateQuestion(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id, 
                             @ModelAttribute(value="question") Question questionDetails) {      
        
        Question temp = questionRepository.findById(id);
        temp.setQuestionName(questionDetails.getQuestionName());
        temp.setQuestionDescription(questionDetails.getQuestionDescription());
        temp.setQuestionImage(questionDetails.getQuestionImage());
        temp.setQuestionKo(questionDetails.isQuestionKo());
        temp.setQuestionTimelimit(questionDetails.getQuestionTimelimit());
        //temp.setAnswers(questionDetails.getAnswers());
        
        questionRepository.save(temp);
        return "redirect:/fragenAdministration";
}
```

My view:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/frageDetail/updateQuestion/{id}(id=${question.id})}" th:object="${question}" th:method="post">

<div class="input"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fragename" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 20px" th:field="*{questionName}"> 
</div>
        
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px">
    <textarea style="resize: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Frage Beschreibung" rows="6" th:field="*{questionDescription}"> </textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:45px;">
        
    <div class="checkbox" th:each="answer : ${answerList}">
        <!-- works, but wont update to database -->
        <input type="checkbox" th:checked="${answer.answerOk}" th:text="${answer.answerName}">      
        
        <!-- error, Invalid property 'answer' of bean class [com.example.demo.model.Question]: 
        Bean property 'answer' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return 
        type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter? -->
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{answer.answerOk}" th:text="${answer.answerName}">        
    </div>      
        
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{questionKo}">KO Frage</label>
</div>
        
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="timeLimit" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="text-align: left;">ZeitLimit</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="time" class="form-control" id="kflgreen" th:field="*{questionTimelimit}">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Everything works fine, except the mapping of the boolean 'answerOk', which is a field in 'Answer.class'.
With th:checked="${answer.answerOk}", the checkbox gets checked if answerOk is true; which is wanted.
But to update the value in the database when I uncheck the checkbox, I have to use th:field (like in th:field="*{questionKo}"; which works perfectly fine for this and all other fields)

The problem is, when I use th:field="*{answer.answerOk}" instead of th:checked="${anwser.answerOk}", I get the error message:

"org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'answer' of bean class [com.example.demo.model.Question]: Bean property 'answer' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?"

I of course have all getter and setter in Answer.class and Question.class.

So does anyone has an idea how to bind the field answerOk, so it will get updated in the database as well when I check/uncheck it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Selection Variable Expressions (*{...}) in combination with `th:object = ${...}.

In your case `*{answerOk}` resolves to `${answer.answerOk}`

```html
<div class="checkbox" th:each="answer : ${answerList}">
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{answerOk}" th:text="${answer.answerName}">        
</div>
```

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax